# JavaScript : How to return a function every time I update some value?

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

Okay, this question might seem a bit abstract but let me make this a little clearer. This is regarding a problem I am trying to solve it using a charting library called Chartist. They have this system called plugin where in you can add some additional functionality on the charts. Now how to write a plugin is explained [here](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-plugin-pointlabels) and at the bottom of this [page](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/plugins.html).
Now I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GlMwIj1jjBdaUYfdVvwc?p=preview) to demonstrate the issue... The issue I am facing is that whenever I click a drop down the value in the axisTitle never changes...
You may ask why?
The reason is these lines of chartist-plugin-axistitle.js

```
      (function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define([], function () {
      return (root.returnExportsGlobal = factory());
    });
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
    // only CommonJS-like enviroments that support module.exports,
    // like Node.
    module.exports = factory();
  } else {
    root['Chartist.plugins.ctAxisTitle'] = factory();
  }
}(this, function () {

  /**
   * Chartist.js plugin to display a title for 1 or 2 axises.
   *
   */
  /* global Chartist */
  (function (window, document, Chartist) {
      'use strict';

      var axisDefaults = {
          axisTitle: '',
          axisClass: 'ct-axis-title',
          offset: {
              x: 0,
              y: 0
          },
          textAnchor: 'middle',
          flipText: false
      };
      var defaultOptions = {
          xAxis: axisDefaults,
          yAxis: axisDefaults
      };

      Chartist.plugins = Chartist.plugins || {};
      Chartist.plugins.ctAxisTitle = function (options) {

          options = Chartist.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);

          return function ctAxisTitle(chart) {


              chart.on('created', function (data) {

                  if (!options.axisX.axisTitle && !options.axisY.axisTitle) {
                      throw new Error('ctAxisTitle plugin - You must provide at least one axis title');
                  } else if (!data.axisX && !data.axisY) {
                      throw new Error('ctAxisTitle plugin can only be used on charts that have at least one axis');
                  }

                  var xPos;
                  var yPos;
                  var title;

                  //position axis X title
                  if (options.axisX.axisTitle && data.axisX) {

                      xPos = (data.axisX.axisLength / 2) + data.options.axisX.offset + data.options.chartPadding.left;

                      yPos = data.options.chartPadding.top;
                      if (data.options.axisX.position === 'end') {
                          yPos += data.axisY.axisLength;
                      }

                      title = new Chartist.Svg("text");
                      title.addClass(options.axisX.axisClass);
                      title.text(options.axisX.axisTitle);
                      title.attr({
                          x: xPos + options.axisX.offset.x,
                          y: yPos + options.axisX.offset.y,
                          "text-anchor": options.axisX.textAnchor
                      });

                      data.svg.append(title, true);

                  }

                  //position axis Y title
                  if (options.axisY.axisTitle && data.axisY) {
                      xPos = 0;


                      yPos = (data.axisY.axisLength / 2) + data.options.chartPadding.top;
                      if (data.options.axisY.position === 'end') {
                          xPos = data.axisX.axisLength;
                      }

                      var transform = 'rotate(' + (options.axisY.flipTitle ? -90 : 90) + ', ' + xPos + ', ' + yPos + ')';

                      title = new Chartist.Svg("text");
                      title.addClass(options.axisY.axisClass);
                      title.text(options.axisY.axisTitle);
                      title.attr({
                          x: xPos + options.axisY.offset.x,
                          y: yPos + options.axisY.offset.y,
                          transform: transform,
                          "text-anchor": options.axisY.textAnchor
                      });

                      data.svg.append(title, true);
                  }

              });
             chart.on('optionsChanged', function(data){
              console.log("Saras");
             }); 
          };
      };

  }(window, document, Chartist));
  return Chartist.plugins.ctAxisTitle;

}));
```

If you put up a console.log just below the `options = Chartist.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);` line. You will see the options changing on dropdown click... but they actually never change, apart from this one time when the chart is created. 
Now I somehow want the updated options to reflect in the return function, but the issue is you can only return it once.

So the question really is  **How do I call the `ctAxisTitle` function again and again on update**
So is this a design flaw? Should the design of plugin be changed, if yes... how?? Or I can manipulate the code in some way to achieve the functionality.

I have also created a [Github](https://github.com/SarasArya/Angular-Chartist-Tab-Example) repo, to quickly get you started on it

Comment: The content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow various random links to help you. Say clearly, right here in the question, what you're trying to do. Show **all** relevant code in the question (not just on plunker). See also: [mcve]

Comment: @Reddy I understand... I have tried to narrow it down with the update. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion this is a design flaw in `angular-chartist.js`. If the data or options are changed they do the following:

```
// If chart type changed we need to recreate whole chart, otherwise we can update
        if (!this.chart || newConfig.chartType !== oldConfig.chartType) {
            this.renderChart();
        } else {
            this.chart.update(this.data, this.options);
        }
```

So when they only rerender the chart when the chart type is changed, this isn't what you want.

If you have this file locally you could just modify that part to match your needs and always render the chart by replacing this lines with `this.renderChart();`

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YmpOeFRkUyJ8myPlTGzd?p=preview) for an example where I did the above.

Comment: Dude that worked... I never thought to look inside angular-chartist... This was a great find... Thanks a ton for this... :)